# Как получить из массива ниже перечисленного member_id, когда is_owner = true

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
array(4) { ["items"]=> array(36) { [0]=> array(5) { ["member_id"]=> int(454598412) ["invited_by"]=> int(454598412) ["join_date"]=> int(1559166975) ["is_admin"]=> bool(true) ["is_owner"]=> bool(true) } [1]=> array(4) { ["member_id"]=> int(-158645511) ["invited_by"]=> int(134582877) ["join_date"]=> int(1534238649) ["is_admin"]=> bool(true) } [2]=> array(4) { ["member_id"]=>  и тд..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array['items'] as $item) // $array - это Ваш массив
{
    if ($item['is_owner'])
    {
        $memberId = $item['member_id'];
        echo "Полученный member_id = ".$memberId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать ф-ю [array_reduce()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php) - `Итеративно уменьшает массив к единственному значению, используя callback-функцию`

Вот пример решения задачи, с ее использованием:

```
echo array_reduce($array["items"], function ($carry, $item) {
    if (!$carry && $item["is_owner"]) $carry = $item["member_id"];
    return $carry;
});
```